# Get values in between <b> tags from web page

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pull two pieces of data from an external web page. There are two  tags on the page, and the data I need is within both.

How would I get the data from both  tags?

I've tried a few different things, but none seem to work. Here's what I tried last:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('url');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('b');
if ($elements->length) {
    echo "found: ", $elements->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: Your query should be `//b`, but you can also use DOMDocument's `getElementsByTagName()` instead of `query()`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not always the answer, in fact for my entire web platform there are less then a dozen instances of regex in my PHP.

```
$p = explode($elements,'<b>')[1];
$p = explode($p,'</b>)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
    $str = "This is a test string <b>I want this sub string</b> this is a test string.";
    preg_match("~".preg_quote("<b>")."(.*?)".preg_quote("</b>")."~", $str, $output);
    echo $output[1];
?>
```

Output:

```
I want this sub string
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function get_str_btwn($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini    = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$dom=file_get_contents('url');
echo get_str_btwn($dom,"<b>","</b>");
```

Comment: you can also call this function to print data between another tags example echo get_str_btwn($dom,"<strong>","</strong>");